# Background service not starting after device restart in Android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-reboot

I have developed an Android application that includes a background service (MainService) designed to run automatically after the device restarts. To achieve this functionality, I have implemented a BootReceiver class and added it to the AndroidManifest.xml file to handle the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED intent. However, despite these efforts, the MainService is not starting automatically after the device restarts.

I have created a BroadcastReceiver class named BootReceiver and added it to my AndroidManifest.xml file to start a background service (MainService) after the device restarts. However, the service is not starting automatically after the device restarts. Below are the relevant parts of my code:

BootReceiver.java:

```
package com.sithum.mediatracker;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            // Start your service here
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MainService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MediaTracker"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".MainService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync|location|mediaPlayback"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">

            <!-- Intent filter if needed -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.sithum.mediatracker.ACTION_START_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have also declared the necessary permissions in the manifest file. And I tested this in android 9 and 11. What could be causing the background service not to start automatically after device restart, and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What happens? Some log messages in strategic places wouldn't hurt.

Comment: In modern Android you can't just have a background service run forever.  They'll be killed after about 2 minutes.  So this isn't a recommended way to do things at all anymore.  If you have a task that needs to be done, use WorkManager.  If you want a permanently running background service, rethink how you architect your app because that will never work on this OS.